# Datos fuera de rango con sentencia between

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, server

tengo la siguiente sentencia en sql para definir los rangos del precio entre 10 y 14:

```
SELECT p.NombreProducto, p.UnidadesPorOrden, do.OrdenId, CAST(do.PrecioUnitario as int) AS PRECIO, do.Descuento
FROM Productos as p
JOIN DetalleOrdenes as do
 ON p.ProductosId = do.ProductoID
WHERE p.PrecioUnitario BETWEEN 10 and 14
ORDER BY P.PrecioUnitario ASC
```

pero cuando la ejecuto los valores devueltos siempre me aparecen valores menores a 10
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien podria explicarme porque sucede y como podría solucionarlo. gracias.

Comment: Estás mostrando un PrecioUnitario y haciendo el filtro a otra columna.

Comment: La columna `CAST(do.PrecioUnitario as int) AS PRECIO` se obtiene del campo `PrecioUnitario` de la tabla `DetalleOrdenes`, sin embargo la restricción `WHERE p.PrecioUnitario BETWEEN 10 and 14` la haces sobre el campo `PrecioUnitario` de la tabla `Productos`. Es muy probable que el valor de una tabla difiera con el de la otra y, por ese motivo, aparecen datos fuera de rango.

Comment: Voto el cierre por tratarse de un error tipográfico.

Comment: Efectivamente eso fue. tenia los campos mal, gracias.